# MYSQL multiple row INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I've been looking everywhere and can't find anything like this. I have two tables, table one `t1` has **12** entries for each `a1` value, `b1` values are static for all `a1` except one entry. neither `a1` or `b1` are primary key. `t1` also has other static columns for all `a1`.

table two `t2` has `a2` and the `b2` value that is not static. neither `a2` nor `b2` are primary keys (I use independent id columns for primary keys).

my goal is to import all `a2` values that do not exist in `t1`. keep in mind table 1 has ~2 million entries currently, and table 2 will generally have 150K-1M entries.

this works:

```
INSERT t1 ( a1, b1, c1, d1 )
SELECT a2, b2, 'constant1', 'constant2'
FROM t2 AS V2
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE a1=V2.a2 )
```

but it only enters one `a2` entry into `t1`, leaving **11** missing entries.

This is my idea:

```
SELECT a2, b2 FROM t2 AS V2
INSERT INTO t1 ( a1, b1, c1, d1 )
       VALUES  ( V2.a2, V2.b2, 'constant1', 'constant2' ),
               ( V2.a2, 'constant3', 'constant1', 'constant2'),
               ( V2.a2, 'constant4', 'constant1', 'constant2'),
               ( V2.a2, 'constant5', 'constant1', 'constant2'),
               ( V2.a2, 'constant6', 'constant1', 'constant2'),
               ( V2.a2, 'constant7', 'constant1', 'constant2'),
               ( V2.a2, 'constant8', 'constant1', 'constant2'),
               ( V2.a2, 'constant9', 'constant1', 'constant2'),
               ( V2.a2, 'constant10', 'constant1', 'constant2'),
               ( V2.a2, 'constant11', 'constant1', 'constant2'),
               ( V2.a2, 'constant12', 'constant1', 'constant2'),
               ( V2.a2, 'constant13', 'constant1', 'constant2')
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE a1=V2.a2 )
```

Is something like this possible? (This obviously doesn't work, major syntax errors).

SAMPLE DATA FROM ACTUAL TABLE:

```
 +---------+------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
 | id      | name | destination | application | durationRate |
 +---------+------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
 |   45013 | 1    | 1305200     | audio       | 0            | 
 |  335203 | 2    | 1305200     | audio       | 0.014        | 
 |  625393 | 3    | 1305200     | audio       | 0.005928     | 
 |  956657 | 4    | 1305200     | audio       | 0            | 
 | 1251735 | 5    | 1305200     | audio       | 0            | 
 | 1560365 | 6    | 1305200     | audio       | 0.02         | 
 | 1868995 | 7    | 1305200     | audio       | 0.014        | 
 | 2200259 | 9    | 1305200     | audio       | 0.014        | 
 | 2517971 | 10   | 1305200     | audio       | 0.018        | 
 | 2813049 | 11   | 1305200     | audio       | 0.018        | 
 | 3121679 | 12   | 1305200     | audio       | 0.00775      | 
 | 3430309 | 8    | 1305200     | audio       | 0            | 
 |   45015 | 1    | 1305201     | audio       | 0            | 
 |  335205 | 2    | 1305201     | audio       | 0.014        | 
 |  625395 | 3    | 1305201     | audio       | 0.006552     | 
 |  956659 | 4    | 1305201     | audio       | 0            | 
 | 1251737 | 5    | 1305201     | audio       | 0            | 
 | 1560367 | 6    | 1305201     | audio       | 0.02         | 
 | 1868997 | 7    | 1305201     | audio       | 0.014        | 
 | 2200261 | 9    | 1305201     | audio       | 0.014        | 
 | 2517973 | 10   | 1305201     | audio       | 0.018        | 
 | 2813051 | 11   | 1305201     | audio       | 0.018        | 
 | 3121681 | 12   | 1305201     | audio       | 0.00775      | 
 | 3430311 | 8    | 1305201     | audio       | 0            | 
 |   45017 | 1    | 1305202     | audio       | 0            | 
 |  335207 | 2    | 1305202     | audio       | 0.014        | 
 |  625397 | 3    | 1305202     | audio       | 0.00468      | 
 |  956661 | 4    | 1305202     | audio       | 0            | 
 | 1251739 | 5    | 1305202     | audio       | 0            | 
 | 1560369 | 6    | 1305202     | audio       | 0.02         | 
 | 1868999 | 7    | 1305202     | audio       | 0.014        | 
 | 2200263 | 9    | 1305202     | audio       | 0.014        | 
 | 2517975 | 10   | 1305202     | audio       | 0.018        | 
 | 2813053 | 11   | 1305202     | audio       | 0.018        | 
 | 3121683 | 12   | 1305202     | audio       | 0.00775      | 
 | 3430313 | 8    | 1305202     | audio       | 0            | 
 +---------+------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
 36 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In my example table, `a1`=`destination`, `b1`=`durationRate`, `c1`=`name`, `d1`=`application`
There 12 different rate decks defined by `name`.

Comment: Why are you expecting it to insert 12 rows from t2 to t1?  Perhaps it would be clearer if you show a small amount of sample data from each of t1 and t2 and therefore which rows you expect to get inserted into t1?

Answer (score 2):

Use more specific condition in `where` clause. I've added here another column but it's going to work only id pair `a1` and `b1` is unique, if it's not you should add more columns to condition.

```
INSERT t1 ( a1, b1, c1, d1 )
SELECT a2, b2, 'constant1', 'constant2'
FROM t2 AS V2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM t1 WHERE a1 = V2.a2 and b1 = V2.b2
)
```

Comment: So, first I should have a command populate t2 with the other 11 entries for each a2?

Comment: @necival, no, not exactly. Which columns do you want to be unique in t1 table? All or only some of them?

Comment: There is one entry to be made in `t1` with `t1.a1`=`t2.a2` and `t1.a1`=`t2.b2` values, and 11 entries with `t1.a1`=`t2.a2` and different but constant values in the `b1` column.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I understand what you want now.

You have 11 rows to be created for each new a2 value that should be populated with the same values that others of the same name column (c1) value would have (side comment - isn't this an opportunity for normalising the tables and reducing the amount of data stored?). Then the twelfth row for a given a2 value should have the unique value for b1 as specified in t2.

One way to create this is first to populate a temporary table with the standard 11 values. Then use that plus the entries in t2 to get the rows to insert

Using SQL Server syntax:

```
insert into @staticValues (c1, otherCol, b1)  
select c1, otherCol, b1  
from t1  
where a1 = 1305202 -- arbitrary sample existing value  
and c1 <> 3 -- ignoring the varying row

insert into t1 (a1, c1, otherCol, b1)  
select t2.a2, sv.c1, sv.otherCol, sv.b1  
from @staticValues sv  
  inner join t2 on t2.a2 = t2.a2 -- equivalent to a cross join  
where not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.a1 = t2.a2)  
union  
select t2.a2, 3, 'audio', t2.b2  
from t2  
where not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.a1 = t2.a2)
```